# How to force fieldset's width smaller than child element's using jquery in chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, width, fieldset

When I have to make a fieldset's width smaller than it's child element's width, chrome and firefox would n't listen to me while internet explorer forces fieldset's width.

Here is my html code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="/Common/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".full").each(function () {
                $(this).siblings().each(function () {
                    $(this).width(500);
                });
            });
            console.log($("#abc").width());
            console.log($("#def").width());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <fieldset id="abc">
            <legend>fieldset 1</legend>
            <div style="width:600px;overflow:hidden;"></div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="def" style="width:500px;">
            <legend>fieldset 2</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <span class="full"></span>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Chrome

[image]

Internet Explorer

[image]

Comment: could you give a fiddle also with css?

Comment: @reyaner There is no extra css as you can see. You can see the result at http://jsfiddle.net/pmmwmdLw/2/

Comment: is setting the `div` inside to `position:absolute;` a soluton for you?

Comment: @reyaner Unfortunatelly, I cannot set position:absolute for my div.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this will work then.

The best you can do, is to put a second div as wrap, and set his width...

```
<fieldset id="abc">
    <legend>fieldset 1</legend>
        <div class="wrap" style="overflow:hidden;">
           <div style="width:600px;overflow:hidden;"></div>
        </div>
</fieldset>
```

and then:

```
$(this).siblings().each(function () {
    $(this).width(500).find("div.wrap").width(500);
});
```

you could also create the wrap div with jQuery...